# RecordTypes not listing in case screen after deployment

Tags: deployment, case, record-type, change-set

In my partial sandbox i have created multiple record-types and their respective page layouts for the CASE screen. In this scenario, when i go to the case screen a page with record-type drop down is coming (which is expected).
[image: Record-type selection dropdown]

This works fine in this sandbox, however, as i deploy these into my developer sandbox using change-set the record-type selection screen with drop down is not coming up. I ensured that all record-type and respective page-layouts has been successfully deployed.

Is it that i should manually add the record-type for the required user profile from developer sandbox?

Can it be assigned along with the deployment process?

**Edit 1 :**

Below screenshot shows the 'Record Type Selection' in Dev sandbox in which an entry `Case` is expected.
[image: Record Type Selection missing the data type CASE]

Below screenshot shows the 'Record Type Selection' in Partial sandbox in which an entry `Case` is present and is not reflected in Dev sandbox.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to assign the permissions for profiles to activate your new record types. That can be done in **Setup/Profiles/[Your Profile]/Object Settings/[Your Record Type Object]/Record Types and Page Layout Assignments** ant there you have to choose Assigned Record Types and also the Default Record Type to be used.

[image]

Then in your change-set, you have to select the profiles you want to include with your deployment:

[image]